# Flakiness encountered when attempting to read table row data after an async operation

Tags: angularjs, xpath, protractor, angular-material

I have a test suite which involves making selections from a couple of select inputs (using Angular Material) which in turn trigger a table to render some results after an async operation completes.

Once the operation completes, I am attempting to read out the values of a single table row so I can perform some assertions on the values in the table cell.

[image]

I am making use of a couple of helpers, one of which takes a string value and uses xpath query to attempt to extract a table row where is finds a row containing table cell that contains the passed in string.

[image]

The problem I am facing is that I my expectation `expect(cells).toBeDefined()` is returning undefined. This happens intermittently, but I would say 75% of the time it fails, so I think the xpath approach is probably not suitable, or I should at least try and wait for at least one table row of data to appear before attempting any assertions. It's worst on our ci server (Jenkins) where it very rarely passes, so it feels like a timing issue of sorts to me.

The screenshot taken by protractor on the test failure is as follows:

[image]

Here the comparison period input has been selected from and the table does show a single record, so hence why I feel like this is a timing issue where the data row has not quite rendered in the table between the time the async fetch of data completes and the expectation is performed.

Has anyone got any suggestions of things I could try here? Any recommended recipes I should be following?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to [use `cssContainingText` as locator](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText). It seems much more suitable for your case

You can get the desired row in once that way just by element-chaining.

It will be something like this:

```
cells = element(by.cssContainingText('td span', 'TAYSIDE')).element(by.xpath('ancestor::tr')).all(by.css('td'));
//first part selects the element of the desired row
//second part of the chain selects the next <tr>-parent-element above
//third part selects all td-elements below the selected <tr>-element

//alternatives:
cells = element(by.cssContainingText('td span', value)).element(by.xpath('..')).$$('td');
//by.xpath('..') to select direct parent
//"$$()" is short for "element.all(by.css())"
```

Overall it would look like this:

```
describe("full scenario", function(){
    var cells;

    beforeAll(function(){
        common.selectComparisonPeriod(initialPeriod);
        //probably no need to use "then()" here.
        browser.wait(helper.waitForElementToHide(common.spinner), 5000);
        cells = element(by.cssContainingText('td span', value))
            .element(by.xpath('ancestor::tr'))
            .$$('td');
    });
    it("executes test", function(){
        expect(cells).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

**further Options:**

- use `it()` instead of `beforeAll()`
- use a `browser.wait()`-condition to ensure cells-definition

in code:

```
describe("full scenario", function(){
    var cells;

    //instead beforeAll, use another it()-block
    it("shall load the correct grid", function(done){
        common.selectComparisonPeriod(initialPeriod);
        //probably no need to use "then()" here.
        browser.wait(helper.waitForElementToHide(common.spinner), 5000);
        cells = element(by.cssContainingText('td span', value))
            .element(by.xpath('ancestor::tr'))
            .$$('td');
        done();
    });
    it("executes test", function(){
        //simplest to just wait for all promises to be resolved (if controlFlow enabled)
        browser.waitForAngular(); 
        //waits until cells is defined, but for max 5 secs
        browser.wait(typeof(cells) != 'undefined', 5000); 
        expect(cells).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I get the same undefined error from protractor

Comment: Did you define cells before the `beforeAll()`? Cuz I just assumed so. Further did I assume your helper-function uses `browser.wait()`. I put now a full example to the answer, in which I additionally wrapped the helper-function in a `browser.wait()` in case the function just returns true/false. I also removed `then()` ... it shouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: Thanks, my `waitForElementToHide` helper does use browser.wait already and yes `cells` is defined already outside of the `beforeAll`. Will try some variations based on your alternatives...

Comment: @mindparse: Thank you for the response. One thing I'd like to add (you probably know it already, but anyway) is that I removed the `.then()`, because it opens an async task, while without `then()` protractor should keep the execution synchronous. And as one more thing, it might be possible to use `browser.waitForAngular();` in the line before `cells = ...`, to ensure, that no promises are left unresolved before the cells-definition. Also `console.log(cells.toString());` can be an indicator; whether it returns `[object Object]` or `undefined`.

Comment: @mindparse : a question that came to my mind: Why do you bother putting the logic into the `beforeAll` and just the check into the `it`? As there is no `beforeEach`, having it all in the `it`-statement seems more logical to me.

Comment: There's a load of other it statements that I haven't included which go on to check the actual values in each of the cells returned. That's the reason for using the beforeAll